# Extract a specific field from JSON output using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON output as follows:

```
{
  "example": {
    "sub-example": [
      {
        "name": "123-345",
        "tag" : 100
      },
      {
        "name": "234-456",
        "tag" : 100
      },
      {
        "name": "4a7-a07a5",
        "tag" : 100
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to extract the values of the three "name" fields and store it in three variables.

I tried `cat json_file | jq '.["example.sub-example.name"]'` to extract the value of the "name" field but that doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this using jq (or some other method)?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

If you just want to extract the `name` fields, the command you're looking for is `jq '.example."sub-example" | .[] | .name'`. If you want to keep the names in an array, wrap the whole `jq` expression in square brackets.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However when I do cat test | jq '.example."sub-example" | .[] | .name' I get the error: error: syntax error, unexpected QQSTRING_START, expecting IDENT
.example."sub-example" | .[] | .name
         ^
1 compile error (with  ^ pointing to the dot after jq '.example)

Comment: Are you using the latest version of `jq`? It worked just fine on my system. I'm using version 1.5 (you can check with `jq --version`).

Comment: It is 1.3 (I downloaded it via apt-get install jq). Is there some other way to get the latest version?I am using Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Comment: If I have some field "name-of-instance" instead of "name", the command jq '.example."sub-example" | .[] | .name-of-instance' doesnt work. Do you have suggestions to fix it?

Comment: That's because it's interpreting `.name-of-instance` as an expression (`.name - of - instance`). Use quotes, like I did in `"sub-example"`.

Comment: How do you extract two fields at a time?

Comment: @PetrusTheron Depends on how you want to extract them. If you want them in an object, for instance, you can just construct it: `.example."sub-example" | .[] | {field1: .field1, field2: .field2}`.

Answer (score 47):

Using jq 1.3 (and later), you can use the filter to extract the values:

```
.example["sub-example"] | .[] | .name
```

Or more compactly:

```
.example["sub-example"][].name
```

These of course also work with later versions of jq as well.

### Reading into shell variables

Rather than populating separate shell variables (which would require knowing in advance how many values there are), consider populating a shell array.  For example, using a bash shell with `mapfile` (aka `readarray`):

```
mapfile -t ary < <(< json_file jq '.example."sub-example"[].name')
```

You could alternatively use a shell `while` loop. Etc etc. There are many SO Qs on this topic.

Answer (score 7):

It's been a few years and I recently had to do this myself so thought I should post another way here.

You can also use `map()` to extract specific fields. e.g.

```
.example."sub-example"|map(.name)
```

Ref: https://jqplay.org/s/N6TboUkELM